# Is it possible to retrieve an organization, position or any facebook wokplace profile information using webhooks and not account management API?

Tags: webhooks, facebook-workplace

Please help. I would like to verify if webhooks from Graph API can retrieve the following fields:
1. Organization
2. Position
3. Department
4. Manager

If not, is it only limited to webhook events indicated in this link, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook#response ?

Answer (score 0):

the webhook sends only the fields specified in the link that you have posted.

To retrieve all the others information, you can use the Graph APIs.